# Retrieving rows that share multiple ID's in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on how to narrow down a selection of rows that are related by multiple ID's. Here is my problem with the data as follows:

```
|Widget   |    |Widget Category     |    |Part Category |    |Part         |
+---------+    +--------------------+    +--------------+    +-------------+
|Id|Name  |    |WidId|CatId|CatName |    |PartId| CatId |    |Id|Name      |
+---------+    +-----+-----+--------+    +------+-------+    +--+----------+
| 1|item01|    |    1|    1|Windows |    |     1|      1|    | 1|Glass     |
| 2|item02|    |    2|    1|Windows |    |     1|      2|    | 2|Door Frame|
| 3|item03|    |    3|    1|Windows |    |     2|      2|    | 3|Wheel     |
| 4|item04|    |    1|    2|Door    |    |     4|      2|    | 4|Handle    |
| 5|item05|    |    5|    2|Door    |    
| 6|item06|    |    6|    3|Trunk   |
```

One or more widgets can be in a Widget Category. Many widget categories can have many part Categories. Many Parts can be part of many part categories. I need to know what Parts are linked to what Widgets. So we know that Item01 has parts "Glass" and Item05 has Parts "Glass, Door Frame, and Handle".

Here is my SQL I have so far but I need it to be dynamic so it can run once a week on a stored procedure.

```
---- This gives me the Correct number of Widgets to Parts based on set of 2 category ID's as a quick and static hack
SELECT W.Id
FROM Widget W
INNER JOIN dbo.[WidgetCategory] WC1 ON WC1.WidId = W.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.[WidgetCategory] WC2 ON WC2.WidId = W.Id
WHERE WC1.CatId = 1 AND WC2.CatId = 2
GROUP BY W.Id
```

The reason for the above query is to get a table structure that is grouped by PartId's to WidgetId's as an intersection of the two related categories and all the widgets that are related to parts. The below table is what I am trying to get so that I can aggregate how many widgets are in a part (COUNT(WidId) GROUP BY PartId):

```
|WidId|PartId|WidgetName|
+-----+------+----------+
|    1|     1|    Item01|
|    2|     1|    Item02|
|    3|     1|    Item03|
|    1|     2|    Item01|
|    5|     2|    Item05|
```

Updated question: How can I get this response from the tables above with only returning the intersection of the two categories?

```
|WidId|PartId|WidgetName|
+-----+------+----------+
|    1|     1|    Item01|
|    1|     2|    Item01|
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Sorry for the sloppiness, had to post quickly before I left for weekend.

**EDIT:** Sorry, about the ProductId, was left over from some SQL that I was using. Should be Widget Id. Added more clarity to the problem and added an addition problem I was having.

Comment: What do you mean it needs to be dynamic?

Comment: Where does ProductID come into the picture? And why a double join on the same table?

Comment: By "Dynamic" I mean that I need to find the intersection of where all Widget Categories that happen to also in each instance of a Part Category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a query like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.WidId, p.ParId, w.Name
FROM Widget w
JOIN WidgetCategory wc ON wc.WidId=w.Id
JOIN PartCategory   pc ON pc.CatId=wc.CatId
JOIN Part           p  ON p.Id=pc.ParId
```

I don't see why you would need to join twice on the WidgetCategory table. What you need is to reach the Part table by joining the PartCategory table.

And why are you grouping? If you want all the parts, then you can't group, unless you use some specific SQL feature to concatenate all the parts in a single row. This may or may not be possible, depending on which database engine you are using.

I added the DISTINCT, just in case you have more than one ways to get from Widget X to Part Y... that is enough to remove duplicates. There is no need for a GROUP BY unless you need to COUNT or do something else with the aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to look over my question, I updated it now that I back to where there is internet service. I am using Microsoft SQL and trying to get the number of widget(s) to a part but only have a link between Widget Category and Part Category.

Comment: I modified the answer very slightly. Have you tried this?

Comment: Is there a way to get the intersection of the two categories where I can get only the result "item01" since it's in both categories but exclude the others since they are not in in both categories? Updated question to reflect this question. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I think you should open another question as this changes things a lot, and you have to provide much more detail. Are there only 2 categories? Do you need parts that match all existing categories? This has to be thought out a bit.

Comment: Thanks, will open up a new question once I can make it better formed and hopefully make sense of what I am trying to accomplish.